# Checking TIME field on MYSQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, time

I am going utterly insane, and need someone to put my out of my misery

I have a field in my MYSQL called 'overide_start_time' which is a standard time type.

I am trying to test whether that field is empty (the field is not defined as null as it can be filled, and then deleted if the time is removed)

I have tried

```
empty()
is_null()
!isset()
```

I have tried logical operators between the statements, but in every single instance the check thinks that there is something in that field, when I have confirmed 100% that field has nothing in it (it is empty, not null)

My exact line of code is

```
<?php if (is_null($row->override_end_time) || empty($row->override_end_time) || !isset($row->override_end_time)) { ?>

A - do something if the value is not set, null or empty

<?php } or { ?>

B - do something if it has something set

<?php }; ?>
```

the field is not filled and in every single instance the if statement continues with B as though it IS set with a value

EDIT : When I do a var_dump($row->override_end_time) the output to the screen is NULL

Comment: what is the result of `var_export($row->override_end_time)` ?

Comment: try `var_dump($row->override_end_time)` this will help you understand what the value is. Post the value of this if it doesn't make sense to you.

Comment: Try doing `if (strtotime($row->override_end_time)) { ... }`, which will make sure the time is valid.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you have string `NULL`  as value of your `$row->override_end_time`. That is not `is_null()` for php, and it is not `empty()` in php, and it `isset()` in php. :-)

Comment: I will work through these comments later, I had to step away yesterday. Thanks

Comment: OP now shows results of VAR_DUMP which is NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Feeling a little bit stupid for trying to be too clever.

All I needed was

```
<?php if ($row->override_start_time == NULL) {...}
```

Thanks to xcloudx for the var_dump suggestion